# How to scroll down

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

The plane that I'm modeling is at the bottom of the screen. I would like it at the top. How do I do this? The scroll wheel makes the view go in circles; I just want that plane part that I'm working on in the middle of my screen.

Comment: if you are just starting with blender please look at the [Resources page](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender), you might find it useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> and drag. For more info click [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html)

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you can key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> and move your mouse around. This is called *panning*. However, some people do not have a 3 button mouse, and cannot utilize the <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> button. If this is the case for you, go to *File > User Preferences > Input tab > Mouse: header* and check *Emulate 3 Button Mouse*. This allows you to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to *pan*.

Note the following:

- <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to rotate.
- <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> to scroll in and out.

To learn more about Blender's navigation tools, and as a great place to start with Blender as a whole, refer to CGCookie's [Introduction to Blender](https://cgcookie.com/flow/introduction-to-blender/).